# Is there a way to use SQL_NO_CACHE MySQL option in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Having a query with many eagerloads (and so many `LEFT OUTER JOIN`), I'm a currently trying to figure out a way to disable MySQL query cache on a per-query basis.

So far I have been unable to find any hint on how I might to that in the documentation.

Simplest example (without joins):

```
result = session.query(MyTable).filter(Object.id == 42)
```

will generate something like:

```
SELECT MyTable.id AS mytable_id, MyTable.stuff as mytable_stuff, …
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyTable.id = 42;
```

I'm looking to generate the following statement instead so it won't try to use or fill the query cache:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE MyTable.id AS mytable_id, MyTable.stuff as mytable_stuff, …
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyTable.id = 42;
```

Is it actually possible?

Comment: Try: [`prefix_with`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Delete.prefix_with). `session.query(MyTable).prefix_with('SQL_NO_CACHE')`.

Comment: @wchiquito Works like a charm, thanks. Mind creating a *"real"* answer so I might accept it?